# Querying ethereum swap data for a specific uniswap pair

Tags: api, graphql, ethereum, blockchain, data-analysis

I try to fetch all swaps for a specific uniswap pair to track the buys and sells of different entities and calculate their pnl.

When I'm fetchting it via the api I only see the one swap where the token was bought but not the other four swaps where the entity sold those tokens again.

Entity: 0x88565bde2d55ea0460acd250f05818acc9b91e99
Token Pair: 0x1Db2B839409eAB8902fd1A9Fd3FFc7cD8E2131Ce
Token (ANON): 0x975bBd66C60b54fedD24E59a241251e261F474DF

I'm using graph ql, to be specific the uniswap subgraph (https://thegraph.com/hosted-service/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2) to fetch the data

Here is the query I'm using in my testcase to get the data of a token pair with the filter on an entity (later I will remove that filter because I want the data for all entities but for now I use that filter to validate it with other data sources in order to see if I'm getting the right data)

```
{
  swaps (orderBy: timestamp, orderDirection: asc, 
    where: {
      and: [
        {pair: "0x1db2b839409eab8902fd1a9fd3ffc7cd8e2131ce"}
        {or:[
          {to: "0x88565bde2d55ea0460acd250f05818acc9b91e99"}
          {sender: "0x88565bde2d55ea0460acd250f05818acc9b91e99"}
        ]}
      ]
    }
    
  ) 
  {
    id
    timestamp
    sender
    to
    amount0In
    amount1In
    amount0Out
    amount1Out
    amountUSD
    transaction {
        id
        blockNumber
        timestamp
    }
  } 
}
```

You can paste this query to the link I provided above to see the response I get.
So you will see there is only one swap as a response.

Now head over to dextools.io and check the swaps:
[dextools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW5hF.png)

Or dexscreener:
[dexscreener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnwHk.png)

Both times I filtered the maker address to 0x88565bde2d55ea0460acd250f05818acc9b91e99 which is the entity I'm validating the results for. You see there are 5 swaps in total, 1 buy and 4 sell. I don't understand why I'm only getting in the api request above the one swap and nothing more.

Would be great if someone is already experienced with analyzing onchain transactions and could help me.
Also if you use another way for fetching that data, I'm also open to other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `Swap` event. The `sender` is `msg.sender`, and normal swap transactions are done via [`RouterV2`](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D) contract.

Consider this SELL swap from your example - [0x18dc2b342bd3f75645b62389a46d12a5aa638fde6257d7f9a3e55dbed0851ce4#eventlogs](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x18dc2b342bd3f75645b62389a46d12a5aa638fde6257d7f9a3e55dbed0851ce4#eventlog) If you search for `Swap` Log the sender is the `RouterV2` and `to` is also `RouterV2` as this is the `SELL` action.
When the user buys tokens, the Tx will be matched, as in that case `to` would be the EOA address.

We use `Transfer` logs instead and filter by `EOA_ADDRESS`, `PAIR_ADDRESS`. So the SELL actions would be `Transfer(EOA, PAIR)`, the BUY action would be `Transfer(PAIR, EOA)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know if I understand it correctly. How will your graph ql query look like to achieve your explained output?
Or do you fetch your data with a different data provider?

Because I'm not sure if I can access the logs with the uniswap subgraph.

Comment: I use very basic ethereum RPC Node and fetch the data rpc client. Not familiar with graphql, I thought you could query there also for Transfer logs, but not sure. If you want, I could add a typescript example, how would I query for the data with simple RPC call.

Comment: I tried it via graph ql but I found out it doesn't provide the necessary log data, now I found a data provider called Covelent which provides the complete log data. I'm now onto it to filter out the needed events and to get the clean swap data for buys and sells. 

But please provide also your approach, I'm interested in how you made it.